# I'm using Notepad++ with JSON viewer and it won't recognize my JSON string

Tags: json, notepad++

Do I have a problem with my JSON string or am I just not using the good viewer?

Here is the string: (Project related info are removed)

```json
    {
    "VAR": [{
        "Q": "aaaaaa",
        "A1": "bbb!",
        "A2": "ccc!",
        "A3": "ddd!"
    }]
    }
```

Comment: the json looks valid. strange seeing an array with just one element, but it is a valid case.

Comment: you can use http://jsonlint.com/ to check, and it shows as valid

Comment: I was going to make 2 JSON file for my website. Can I put my whole dynamic content in it?

Comment: @fbfcn thanks, but my json works until I get more then 19 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try jsminnpp plugin in notepad++.

Parser is better

Answer (score 0):

My current version of the Notepad++ is v7.8.2 (32-bit) and JSON viewer 1.21.

I assume that the JSON viewer plugin is installed.

The ways it worked for me is firstly select the json text by pressing Ctrl + a then click Plugins > JSON Viewer > Format JSON.

Tell me if it works, you have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I often have formatting issues with notepad++. Google search brought me here. I tried Sun Junwen's tool and it's able to parse where json viewer failed.

https://www.sunjw.us/jstool/npp/

No affiliation; Highly recommend